# Trouble converting an editable to a string (username/password test)

Tags: android, if-statement, tostring

I'm trying to create a simple username/password login screen.  I have the layout done, and right now, I'm trying to set it so when the username `(EditText) == "crete"`, then it should do something.  Here is my code...:

```
public class Login extends Activity {
   public static EditText username, password;
   public Button loginbutton;
   boolean accessgranted;
   public String dbu, dbp, user1;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.login);

       username = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.username);
       password = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.password);        
       loginbutton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);

       user1 = "crete";

       loginbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
               dbu = (username.getText()).toString();
            }
            finally{
               if (dbu == user1){
                   username.setText("SUCCESS");
               }
            }
         }
       });
    }
}
```

this, sadly, doesn't work.  It correctly converts it to a string (i think) because when I tested this code out :

```
 loginbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
        try{
              dbu = (username.getText()).toString();
        }
        finally{
                username.setText("done" + dbu);
            }
        }

     }
});
```

It correctly enters what you entered into the `EditText`, plus the word "done".

There seems to be a problem with creating if-then statements??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You test for `String` equality with the method `.equals("String")`.

With `==` you are testing if the references to the objects are equal.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `equalsIgnoreCase(String)` instead of the `==` comparator.

Like this: `dbu.equalsIgnoreCase(user1)`

Answer (score 1):

`dub` and `user1` are two separate String objects.  You're comparing them like this: `dbu == user1`.  This will always return false.  Instead, replace it with `dbu.equals(user1)`.